# Array value erased when new values added php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two sections of a webpage that will add to a single array for scheduling appointments with some addons. Here is my code to add the ID of one of the addons to the array:

```
if($_POST['marketing'] ==  '64251'){

            $FinalAddons[] = $_POST['marketing'];           
        }
```

When I do that, I can immediately load the results of the array and display that ID as follows:

```
foreach($FinalAddons as $test){
        echo '<p>'.$test.'</p>';
    }
```

However, I have another section with some other addons that, whether or not they are added, will erase the ID for the marketing addon in the array. Here is my code to add the other addons:

```
foreach($AddlAddons as $addons){                
                array_push($FinalAddons, $addons);
            }
```

If I print this out in the same way as I did for the marketing section, it will print out the IDs of the addons just added, but it won't also include the ID for the marketing that was added. All of them are being added to the same array, but it seems like the second addons section overwrites the first section. How do I fix it so that it just adds to the array and not overwrite it?

Update: So, let me clarify how the values are being added to the array. The individual values being added to the array exist inside of two different functions, however, those values get POSTed, via Jquery AJAX, to a PHP switch section, which is where the values are actually being added. I will link a small section of the switch section, which exists outside of all functions ('func' is what the POST uses to determine which switch is being used):

```
$FinalAddons = array();

if(isset($_POST['func']) && !empty($_POST['func'])){
switch($_POST['func']){
case 'addlChoices':
            $AddonKeys = array_keys($_POST);
            foreach($AddlAddons as $addons){
                if($addons == 'func'){continue;}
                array_push($FinalAddons, $addons);
            }
            AdditionalDetails($FinalAddons);
                break;
case 'Marketing':
        if($_POST['marketing'] ==  '64251'){

            $FinalAddons[] = $_POST['marketing];            
        }           
            addons($FinalAddons);
                break;
    }
}
```

I am also only passing the $FinalAddons array into the functions to determine whether or not they are being added, I don't need them passed into either of those functions for them to work.

Comment: Any chance you are copying (or passing by copy) the array in between?

Comment: `$FinalAddons[]=$addons;`

Comment: are these happening within separate functions?

Comment: Make sure you declare `$FinalAddons` before you use it in the `if-loop`

Comment: Are you sure variable is visible for both contexts not just for each one separately? I mean if scope is correct as you did not show us code as whole. Otherwise it seem it should be working.

Comment: I updated my question with additional details to show how the values are being added.